# JavaScript/Node converting variable to class

Tags: javascript, node.js

it's me again with a new noobish question. I have the following Blessed for NodeJS variable:

```
var box = blessed.box({
  width: '100%',
  height: 1,
  content: someContent,
  tags: true,
  style: {
    fg: 'white',
    bg: 'magenta',
    hover: {
      bg: 'green'
    }
  }
});
```

I will be creating multiple of these, and it wouldn't be optimal to declare each one, so I think a class would be perfect. What confuses me is the blessed.box thing. I don't know how to implement it into a class.

How can I create a reusable class with the above parameters? Thanks.

EDIT:

Okay, I figured out how to reuse the above variable - it's just a matter of adding it in a function:

```
function createBox (content, top) {
  var box = blessed.box({
    width: '100%',
    height: 1,
    top: top,
    content: content,
    tags: true,
    style: {
      fg: 'white',
      bg: 'magenta',
      hover: {
        bg: 'green'
      }
    }
  });
  screen.append(box);

  box.on('click', function(data) {
    box.setContent('{center}Some different {red-fg}content{/red-fg}.{/center}');
    screen.render();
  });
};
```

This function can then be called any number of times:

```
createBox('someContent', 1);
createBox('someContent', 2);
```

Sorry for asking before thinking it through. Turned out to be easy.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I understand your question. It feels like you want to know how to implement above in a class syntax. Which in any case is just syntactic sugar from es15. Hope this helps. I am using the spread operator for passed options.

```
class Blessed {
    constructor(...options) {
        this.width = options.width;
        //... the rest of your properties here
    }
}

const box = new Blessed({
    width: '100%',
    height: 1,
    content: someContent,
    tags: true,
    style: {
        fg: 'white',
        bg: 'magenta',
        hover: {
            bg: 'green'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation. I was just trying to figure out how to reuse the variable code (for 5 boxes for example), instead of declaring it 5 times. I figured it out in my EDIT shortly after I asked :/

Comment: Ah I see. Goodluck! You can also wrap your function and return the box as an object. So function Blessed returns box as an object that means you will get the same effect as Blessed.box without having the parent function scope